# Dickey Fuller result interpretation

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

```
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                -5.974572e+00
p-value                        1.900918e-07
#Lags Used                     1.900000e+01
Number of Observations Used    1.594000e+03
Critical Value (5%)           -2.863355e+00
Critical Value (1%)           -3.434459e+00
Critical Value (10%)          -2.567736e+00
dtype: float64
```

Here's the photo of my series and the result of dickeyfuller test on my difference timeseries-the differencing is one day as i have quarter hour solar power data.

[Plot of differenced and Dickey Duller results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y67pp.jpg)

First and foremost the solar data values are in the range 0-5 and the differenced is shown in the photo.
Now my Dickey Fuller test statistic as well as the p value is extremely small. Is that a cause of concern. If not since my p value is very small and te test statistic is smaller than all 3 critical values do i assume my differenced timeseries is stationary. Also what's with the lags.How to change it if incorrect.

Comment: yes you can reject the null hypothesis of testing the presence of unit root and can accept that your time series is stationary.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with such small values of the test statistic and the p value?

Comment: the small value of p gives us more confidence to reject the null hypothesis so there is nothing to worry about.